# How to setup dji L2 api demo?

Tags: joystick, demo

I'm intended to create an android app in which you can control the drone (in my case phantom 2 vision) I want to control it using a virtual joystick, I already have the Level 2 API. To do that I wanted to see a "working app" with my own eyes, to understand how I should use the API. I tried to run the dji demo application (I followed the steps they pointed on the documentation, like put the api key in the manifest), the application seems to work ok, but I only can control the gimbal, the virtual joystick does not work for some reason. Is there any limitation in terms of android OS version, devices, phantom firmware version etc?. I made some questions on dji's forum but no one gave me a concrete answer, I hope some one here can give me a hint :)

I'm using a Samsung galaxy note 10.1. I'm working on the DJI-SDK-Android-V2.4.0 project.

I could get "D/GsProtocolJoystickDemoActivity: GroundStationResult GS_Result_Failed"
while I was debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Since you could invoke the API from gimbal and camera correctly, I am assuming that you have already activated your app. Here is my point, the virtual joystick could be used only in the ground station mode. My suggestions are as following:

1. Turn the remote controller mode to the F mode
2. Invoke DJIDrone.getDJIGroundStation().openGroundStation().
3. Invoke the joystick methods.

**Please Note**: The app key should have the LEVEL2 access so that you could invoke the Ground Station relative methods.